# How to use other machine memory, using A computer memory by B computer with Python?

Tags: python, memory-management, shared-memory

how can i use other computer's memory on my machine with Python, I'm using Windows ?
Is there any module which supports network rendering  or anything which supports to do a particular task on my all the machines available in my network, only I want to use memory here, but if there is anything more efficient thats awesome too !!

Let me clear my question here, I want to use memory(processor, RAM) of my network computers, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: borrow memory card from the other machine is the easiest

Comment: Well, not that it helps you, if those were linux x64_64 systems, then [jumbomem](http://www.ccs3.lanl.gov/~pakin/software/jumbomem/) could let you run python with access to the memory on both systems.

Comment: Are you trying to implement distributed processing? Did you check out http://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributedProgramming?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, in any case you can't directly use memory of another machines. You need to run a client program on auxiliary machines which is able to be instructed to execute tasks.

This means that you need something already prjected to be scalable, since you need to have single tasks to be able to dispatch them around, or write it on your own but it's a complicated story.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jack, your question is vague, but you might be interested in python [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) that allows to create program involving multiple processes on remote machines.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply all, Let me clear my question here, I want to use memory(processor, RAM) of my network computers, how can I do that?

Comment: @junky your new question is not clearer, 'use memory' is vague as hell. What is your exact purpose ? Are you even trying to develop a precise software ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) out for a list of multiprocessing python libraries. There are a few cluster based solutions which will allow you to use network based workers.